Makefile error when including dependency file
I am adding dependency file support to a Makefile project. I have successfully used dependency file data in previous makefile projects, but this time make is reporting an error I have never seen before.
The dependency files are produced with this command:
g++ -c /path/to/myfile.cpp -O2 -fPIC -Wall -MMD -I/include/path -o myfile.d

The file myfile.d is generated without any errors. Then make reloads the makefile and includes the dependecy files:
DEP_FILES=myfile.d
-include $(DEP_FILES)

At this point, make reports these errors:
myfile.d:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored
myfile.d:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

In my experience dependency files have never been a big challenge. In this case, I literally copied the rules from another project on the same system. The directory structure in the new project is larger, so after the error appeared, I simplified the problem by storing (and including) the dependency files in the same directory as the Makefile. But even so, the issue persists.
Online search has produced nothing helpful. What could be the problem here?

Please [edit] your question to show the result of file myfile.d.  I suspect it's an object file.  If you want to specify the name of the dependency file output by the compiler try something like -MF myfile.d (I think).

It appears that the content of the myfile.d file is corrupted: that error means there is a nul character (byte with ASCII code 0) on the file, which is of course wrong.  Have you looked at the contents of that file?  Do they look correct to you?  The problem is that you are using the -o option to write the object content to the .d file which is wrong.  Are you SURE that this is the EXACT compile line used to generate dependency files, that works elsewhere?  I don't think it is.

The file myfile.d was indeed an ELF file, so yeah, probably an object file. After seeing these comments, I changed the dependency build rule to ${CPP} -c $< ${CPP_OPTS} -MM ${INC_DIR_FLAGS} > $@. And everything works. Now I need to fix the other projects where the .d files are also ELF files, but make never complained. I am mildly curious why this was not a problem in other projects, but I have other fires to put out so I will let it go. Thanks to both of you for your insights!

It can't be the case that make didn't complain about including object files.  In those other projects either the GCC command line was written so that the depends file was output to the .d file at the same time as the object file was written to the .o file (GCC can do this), or else you didn't actually include those files into your makefile.

GCC's dependency-generating options are a bit fiddly with respect to where the output goes.  In all cases, the dependency data replaces the preprocessor's normal output inasmuch as that is externalized.  In some cases, that is then produced instead of an object file or executable, but in other cases it is produced in addition to object file or executable.  Depending on which of those cases is being exercised, the meanings of some other options -- especially -o -- vary.  Additional options tweak details of the generated dependency file.
In the command

g++ -c /path/to/myfile.cpp -O2 -fPIC -Wall -MMD -I/include/path -o myfile.d


there are two main options bearing on dependency file generation: -MMD and -o myfile.d.  Together these say:

generate both an object file and a dependency file (-E is not implied, unlike with some related options)

the dependency data are to be written to myfile.d, as determined by replacing the .d suffix of myfile.d with .d

the compiled result is also to be written to file myfile.d


It seems not only plausible, then, but likely that the dependency data is being overwritten with the compiled object.
Alternatives that should work better to generate both object file and dependency data in the same run, ignoring system headers, include:
g++ -c /path/to/myfile.cpp -O2 -fPIC -Wall -MMD -I/include/path

or
g++ -c /path/to/myfile.cpp -O2 -fPIC -Wall -MMD -I/include/path -o myfile.o

or
g++ -c /path/to/myfile.cpp -O2 -fPIC -Wall -MMD -I/include/path -MF myfile.d -o myfile.o

One of the main ideas to take from this is that when GCC is both preprocessing and compiling, it interprets the -o option to specify the name of the primary output: the object file or executable being generated.  This makes it convenient to add dependency-file generation as a side effect of an existing compilation command (-MD or -MMD option), as the existing options generally don't need to be adjusted.
